# Intellij IDEA Groovy "No candidates found for method call"

Tags: jenkins, intellij-idea, jenkins-groovy

I followed all the instructions in the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123890/configuring-groovy-sdk-within-intellij-idea)

But when I associate a file as "Groovy" I see the "no candidates found for method call" on all the groovy commands like "pipeline", "environment", etc in my groovy scripts.

I tried downloading the groovy SDK from apache as well as brew, but both result in the same issue.

Comment: There is a related request specifically for Jenkins file support: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158104